# Azure Active Directory authentication : Showing a modal dialog box or form Error

Tags: azure, iis, azure-active-directory

I have set up an Azure active directory authentication function in my ASP.net web application which works fine when executed in **IIS Express**

[image: Image of Login Screen displayed]

But when I'm trying to run it on the **Server** or **Local IIS** it displays an error message saying

`Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.`

The line of code which is being executed to bring up the login window is (within an async buttonclick event)

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
try
{
     result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
}
```

Is there any workaround to get rid of this ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp

Comment: above example uses Microsoft Owin library (Which I had tried and got no success) I'm using ADAL library for this scenario.

Comment: @NiroshSns Did you ever find a solution to this problem? i am having the same issue.

Comment: Sort of. I gave up this and found whole another way to do azure authentication with asp.net forms applications which works fine.

Comment: Yep, thats what i was thinking i would have to do. Could you steer me in the right direction? @NiroshSns

Comment: I've done it with Json and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory libraries. The code is too hefty to post here as the answer. Check out this [link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488511/acquire-aad-token-using-asp-net-web-forms/43537198