# AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found when acquiring the code using "{prompt", "none"}"

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, adal

So I use `ADAL` library to get id token.
I got the code sample  from here 
[sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488511/acquire-aad-token-using-asp-net-web-forms/43537198#43537198)

However, if I set the query string `prompt` to `none`. I would get this annoying message `AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials.` If the user is not logged in when getting the code. And the screen will hang in the Microsoft login window.

I need to set it as `"prompt", "consent"` so even not logged in the user can still perform sign in/consent. But I wan to simply the process, not to get the user go through this sign in/consent every time.

Is there a way to do it so that for not already sign in user an call back error is returned instead of this error and hanging there forever?

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), `{prompt", "none"}` should be a valid configuration.

I copy the sample code here for convenient purpose:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Params["code"] != null)
        {
            var accesstoken = AcquireTokenWithResource(resource: "https://graph.microsoft.com/");

            Response.Write(accesstoken);
        }
    }


    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetAuthorizationCode();
    }

    public void GetAuthorizationCode()
    {
        JObject response = new JObject();

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "response_type", "code" },
                { "client_id", "clientid" },
                { "redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8099/WebForm1.aspx" },
                { "prompt", "none"},
                { "scope", "openid"}
            };

        var requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/authorize?{1}", EndPointUrl, BuildQueryString(parameters));

        Response.Redirect(requestUrl);

    }
    public string AcquireTokenWithResource(string resource)
    {
        var code = Request.Params["code"];
        AuthenticationContext ac =
    new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", "tenantID"
                              ));
        ClientCredential clcred =
            new ClientCredential("clientID", "clientSecret");
        var token =
            ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code,
                       new Uri("http://localhost:8099/WebForm1.aspx"), clcred,resource).Result.AccessToken;

        return token;
    }
    private string BuildQueryString(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            list.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", parameter.Key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameter.Value)));
        }

        return string.Join("&", list);
    }

    protected string EndPointUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", "https://login.microsoftonline.com", "tenantID", @"oauth2/");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Prompt none is used for implicit flow. The error is expected. Have you tried not specifying the prompt at all?

Comment: Yes I did, I did not know that prompt none is used for implicit flow, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the detailed logs of this error. If you are you using ADAL login the it could be local storage caching issue. as when ADAL login is successful it caches the login info into your browser’s local storage to eliminate the need to log in again anytime soon but in certain situations where you will be authenticating against multiple Azure AD instances it will mix-up the authentication. To fix this you will need to clear the browser's storage cache by using the developer tools(F12) then browse to “Application” tab, and then find your tenant from the “Local Storage” -section.  After removing all the storage entries for ADAL refresh the page that threw the error before and you should be greeted with a fresh login screen.

Hope it helps.