# AcquireTokenAsync asp.net failing modal dial box or form

Tags: asp.net, azure

C# ASP.NET web page that has requirement to MFA to Azure SQL Database.
I have working in development environment.
When I deploy to web server error is received of...
"Showing a modal dial box or form when the application is not running."
I understand why it doesn't work, but how do I get a redirect to work against Azure SQL Database to get a token for the SQL Connection ?
Best answer was:
[Acquire AAD token using ASP.Net web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488511/acquire-aad-token-using-asp-net-web-forms)

What am I missing to make MFA to Azure SQL work in asp.net?

```
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                parameters.Resource,  // "https://database.windows.net/"
                _clientId,
                _redirectUri,
                new AD.PlatformParameters(AD.PromptBehavior.Auto),
                new AD.UserIdentifier(
                    parameters.UserId,
                    AD.UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up, I have the basics of this worked out.
Enable HTTPS (this was an on-prem, internal use web app, was not https, it is now).
Ensure .net 4.7.2
Ensure URI()'s match azure application registration (was missing this)
The redirect and URI back are causing me to change the design and flow of the web page, but that's a side effect of the MFA requirement.
Will post some follow up code example once i have it working the way it should, but a quick test has it working, much easier in windows application as opposed to a web app.