# MicrosoftTeams cmdlets not working with AccessToken

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to run cmdlets from powershell module MicrosoftTeams (version 2.0.0) in a C# web application. I am using Authorization code flow and code from the answer provided in this post to acquire token: [Acquire AAD token using ASP.Net web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488511/acquire-aad-token-using-asp-net-web-forms). Note: I had changed resource in the code to graph.windows.net to acquire AAD token. Token is acquired by using AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync Method.

Once the token is acquired, I run the following lines to create a powershell instance in C# and to import MicrosoftTeams Module.

```
PowerShell pshell
InitialSessionState iss;
iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
iss.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MicrosoftTeams" });
pshell = PowerShell.Create(iss);
```

Then to connect with MicrosoftTeams, I run the following code:

```
var connectCmd = new Command("Connect-MicrosoftTeams");
connectCmd.Parameters.Add("AadAccessToken", AccessToken);
connectCmd.Parameters.Add("AccountId", "xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com");
pshell.Commands.AddCommand(connectCmd);
var result1 = pshell.Invoke();
```

Code works fine till here.

After this I clear the shell commands and invoke the Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy cmdlet:

```
pshell.Commands.Clear();
pshell.Streams.Error.Clear();

pshell.AddScript("Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy");
var result2 = pshell.Invoke();
```

After Invoke, I get an exception and this dialog pops up:

[image]

Pressing 'Continue' brings back the same dialogue a couple of times.

Exception details from this screen are:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232969
  Message=The given key was not present in the dictionary.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
       at Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.Powershell.Connect.Models.AzureSessionProvider.GetAccessToken(String resource, IEnumerable`1 scopes) in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Connect\Models\AzureSession.cs:line 80
       at Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.Powershell.Connect.TeamsPowerShellSession.GetAccessToken(String resource, IEnumerable`1 scopes) in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Connect\TeamsPowerShellSession.cs:line 82
       at Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Connect.GetCsInternalAccessToken.ProcessRecord() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Connect\GetCsInternalAccessToken.cs:line 61
       at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

After pressing continue for the 3rd time, control goes back to C# code, and I receive the following runtime exception:

```
Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): 
"Exception calling "GetRemoteNewCsOnlineSession" with "1" argument(s): 
"Run either Connect-MicrosoftTeams or new-csonlinesession before running cmdlets.""
```

Trying to run this logic from the powershell editor shows similar behavior:

Running the following two lines:

```
$AccessToken =  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AadAccessToken $AccessToken -AccountId 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
```

gives this result:

```
Account                         Environment Tenant                               TenantId                            
-------                         ----------- ------                               --------                            
xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com AzureCloud  xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I then run Get-Team cmdlet:

```
Get-Team -User xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

which results in this message:

```
Get-Team : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Team -User xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Team], KeyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException,Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.GetTeam
```

Running cmdlet Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy yields this

```
Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): 
"Exception calling "GetRemoteNewCsOnlineSession" with "1" argument(s): 
"Run either Connect-MicrosoftTeams or new-csonlinesession before running cmdlets.""
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MicrosoftTeams\2.0.0\net472\SfBORemotePowershellModule.psm1:11369 char:13
+             $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myI ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletInvocationException
```

If I run Connect-MicrosoftTeams directly without providing access token and accountid, I get the login screens and after login everything works fine but not happening with AadAccessToken.

Same code works fine if connecting to AzureAD module via Connect-AzureAD cmdlet like this both in web application and powershell editor:

```
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $AccessToken -AccountId 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
```

If someone has faced and successfully resolved this issue or have some tips on how to resolve this, please help.

I have already tried a lot of things including searching for the specific exception messages and any possible solutions but found nothing that could help in this particular scenario, installed the latest version of MSTeams module, the previous version was old and did not have all the cmdlets that I am looking to work with. I actually installed the preview version of MSTeams module also to see if this issue is fixed in the upcoming release. Uninstalled the deprecated SkypeForBuisnessOnline Connector module, updated windows and so on. If you look at Example 4 in the Microsoft documentation for [Connect-MicrosoftTeams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps#example-4), this is what I am following.

Comment: Which flow are you using to get the token? Client credential, delegated etc? As far as I know you can only use a token acquired by a user for the teams cmdlets at the moment. Perhaps that adding impersonate_user permissions on the app registration might solve this.

Comment: I am using Authorization code flow where the user is redirected to the azure ad login page. After successful login and MFA, access token is returned which can be retrieved in the application. Where can I find the impersonate_user permission in azure? I don't see such permission in API Permissions section.

Comment: How did you go with connecting to Microsoft Teams using the AadAccessToken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your implementation, I will explain them one by one below.

The [answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488511/acquire-aad-token-using-asp-net-web-forms?answertab=votes#tab-top) generates an Microsoft Graph access token rather than an AAD Graph access token. But you put it as the `-AadAccessToken`. You should put it as `-MsAccessToken` here because `Get-Team` is calling Microsoft Graph. But we cannot simply use `Connect-MicrosoftTeams -MsAccessToken $AadAccessToken-AccountId 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'` because the `-AadAccessToken` is necessary. So for testing purpose, we could set it as the same as `-MsAccessToken`.

So you can use this cmd to connect to Microsoft Teams:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AadAccessToken $AadAccessToken -MsAccessToken $AadAccessToken -AccountId 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
```

Then you can run `Get-Team -User xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com` successfully.

But there will be another issue here. `Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy` is a cmd under Skype For Business Powershell module. We have to run either `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` (in Teams module) or `new-csonlinesession` (in SFB module) before running cmdlets.

It means that `Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy` is **NOT** calling Microsoft Graph or AAD Graph.

So the connection method using `-AadAccessToken` and `-MsAccessToken` is **NOT** enough for you to run this command from the SFB module.

I know you don't want to perform login interactively again here for running Powershell cmd. However, since your account has already enabled MFA, static login will no longer apply.

So next I tried to connect with a service principal by following Example 3 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps#example-3).

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -TenantId c3eac90d-eb4b-48ef-ac86-7acac472d3cd -CertificateThumbprint 9b6ac64bfb8b48dbb53cca75fb33ce2d -applicationid daaaf729-aaff-45ba-8055-a39dd618fe24
```

Then the error `Run either Connect-MicrosoftTeams or new-csonlinesession before running cmdlets.` is bypassed **BUT** I got a new error when I run `Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy:

```
Exception calling "GetRemoteNewCsOnlineSession" with "1" argument(s): "Tenant Domain is empty"
```

But I clearly specified the tenant id when I logged in with the service principal.

So I think that the Microsoft Teams module is not well integrated with SFB module currently.

Your design cannot be implemented in this way.

Hope all my findings are helpful.

Comment: I had changed resource to graph.windows.net in my code but forgot to mention. I tested with the same value for `-MsAccessToken` and `-AadAccessToken`. Then running `Get-Team -User xx@xx.xyz.com` I got error: `Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.` SFBO is deprecated and Microsoft is asking to use Teams module. On inspecting cmdlets available in latest teams module, I see that `Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy` is available:`(Get-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams).ExportedCommands`. `Get-Teams` and `Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy` work fine when I run `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` without any params.Thanks

Comment: @kshab You should get a Microsoft Graph token rather than AAD Graph token (this can resolve error `Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.`). I have mentioned it in my answer. And I know that `Get-Teams` and `Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy` work fine when you run `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` without any params. This is because it gets a Microsoft Graph access token for calling `Get-Teams` and another access token (maybe it's for SFB) for calling `Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy`.

Comment: @kshab But when you use `Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AadAccessToken $AadAccessToken -MsAccessToken $AadAccessToken -AccountId 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'` to connect, it only gets an AAD graph token and a Microsoft Graph token. There is not a token for calling SFB. So according to my research, `Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy` cannot be called in this way. If you have anything unclear, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Since Microsoft has been claiming that _"SFBO cmdlets are now integrated into the Teams Powershell Module"_ [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/teams/?view=teams-ps), one would assume that `Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy` is part of Teams module, but apparently there are still integration issues between SFBO and Teams module.

Comment: when you say that "Your design can not be implemented in this way", is there any other way it can be implemented so that the SFBO cmdlets that are now part of Microsoft Teams module start working?

Comment: @kshab No workaround currently, unless you use `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` directly.